# MySQL for replace with wildcard

Tags: mysql, sql, replace

I'm trying to write a SQL update to replace a specific xml node with a new string:

```
UPDATE table
SET Configuration = REPLACE(Configuration,
     "<tag>%%ANY_VALUE%%</tag>"
     "<tag>NEW_DATA</tag>");
```

So that

`<root><tag>SDADAS</tag></root>`

becomes

`<root><tag>NEW_DATA</tag></root>`

Is there a syntax im missing for this type of request?

Comment: What happens when you run the query?

Comment: Can you just do `<tag>%</tag>`?

Comment: @Smandoli running this query will replace the literal string "ANY_VALUE". I'm looking for it to replace a wildcard string.

Comment: @2unco ive tried that and it doesn't do any sort of wildcarding

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Update: MySQL 8.0 has a function [REGEX_REPLACE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace).

Below is my answer from 2014, which still applies to any version of MySQL before 8.0:

---

REPLACE() does not have any support for wildcards, patterns, regular expressions, etc. REPLACE() only replaces one constant string for another constant string.

You could try something complex, to pick out the leading part of the string and the trailing part of the string:

```
UPDATE table
SET Configuration = CONCAT(
      SUBSTR(Configuration, 1, LOCATE('<tag>', Configuration)+4),
      NEW_DATA,
      SUBSTR(Configuration, LOCATE('</tag>', Configuration)
    )
```

But this doesn't work for cases when you have multiple occurrences of `<tag>`.

You may have to fetch the row back into an application, perform string replacement using your favorite language, and post the row back. In other words, a three-step process for each row.

Comment: wow, thank you for the creative solution! I was in the midst of doing an applications-side solution (like you alternatively suggested), but I think your SQL "limited" solution will work against teh constraints of my problem.

Comment: I had some unpredictable results with this, maybe I wasn't careful enough. I'd like to see some more examples, preferably with some precautions like "where" in case one of the "tags" isn't matched.