# MySQL remove text where %startcode%endcode%

Tags: mysql, regex, replace

I have a movie database and one of my columns has codes like this:

```
<div class="video">
<script type="text/javascript">document.write(doit('UEdsbWNtRnRaU0J6Y21NOUltaDBkSEE2THk5MGFHVjJhV1JsYjNNdWRIWXZaVzFpWldRdGRtMXNOR3R1YjJNd2FXTmlMVGN5T0hnME1UQXVhSFJ0YkNJZ2QyVmlhMmwwUVd4c2IzZEdkV3hzVTJOeVpXVnVQU0owY25WbElpQnRiM3BoYkd4dmQyWjFiR3h6WTNKbFpXNDlJblJ5ZFdVaUlHRnNiRzkzWm5Wc2JITmpjbVZsYmowaWRISjFaU0lnWm5KaGJXVmliM0prWlhJOUlqQWlJRzFoY21kcGJuZHBaSFJvUFNJd0lpQnRZWEpuYVc1b1pXbG5hSFE5SWpBaUlITmpjbTlzYkdsdVp6MGlibThpSUhkcFpIUm9QU0kzTWpnaUlHaGxhV2RvZEQwaU5ERXdJajQ4TDJsbWNtRnRaVDQ9'));</script>
<iframe src="http://thevideos.tv/embed-vml4knoc0icb-728x410.html" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" allowfullscreen="true" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" width="728" height="410"></iframe></div>
```

Now I like to remove or replace with '' that javascript.
Ive tried:

```
UPDATE `mytable` SET `column` = replace(column, '%<script%script>%', '')
```

but this dont work,
I like my output to be just like this:

```
<div class="video">
<iframe src="http://thevideos.tv/embed-vml4knoc0icb-728x410.html" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" allowfullscreen="true" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" width="728" height="410"></iframe></div>
```

Any idea? thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL for replace with wildcard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001172/mysql-for-replace-with-wildcard)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should check [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) instead of making this UPDATE

You can remove certain tags and let other pass, in this case:

```
$a = "<div clas...." // All your code
$a_cleaned = strip_tags($a, '<div><iframe>');
```

It's more clear if only you need to scape `<script>` tag

Answer (score 0):

Mysql does not accept wildcards for the `replace` method.

This question has been asked before.
Please see [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001172/mysql-for-replace-with-wildcard).
It might contain a solution for your problem.