# Complex MySQL Find Replace

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I need to find and replace links via mysql: all instances of "https://www.scribd.com/doc/uniquenumber/nameofthedocument" to "https://www.hrnerr.org/doc/?doc=uniquenumber"?

I know that mysql doesn't do wildcards so maybe there's better method. There are 169 instances of the scribd (old) location that needs to be replaced with the new location.

```
UPDATE wp_whaz19_posts SET `post_content`
= REPLACE (`post_content`,
"https://www.scribd.com/doc/257828321/Piermont-Marsh-Fact-Finding-Meeting-    3-Summary-010715",
"https://www.newlink.org/doc/?doc=257828321");
```

or in other words;

```
UPDATE wp_whaz19_posts SET `post_content`
= REPLACE (`post_content`,
"https://www.scribd.com/doc/*",
"https://www.newlink.org/doc/?doc=*");
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL for replace with wildcard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001172/mysql-for-replace-with-wildcard)

Comment: Even if it did do wildcards that won't work as you will get `https://www.newlink.org/doc/?doc=257828321/Piermont-Marsh-Fact-Finding-Meeting-    3-Summary-010715` instead of `https://www.newlink.org/doc/?doc=257828321` Looks like you will need to write a script.

Answer (score 1):

If your old and new URLs are fixed as above does this do the job for you :
UPDATE wp_whaz19_posts SET `post_content`=REPLACE(LEFT(`post_content`, LOCATE('/', `post_content`, 28)-1), 'https://www.scribd.com/doc/', 'https://www.newlink.org/doc/?doc=')

Comment: wouldn't that result in     https://www.newlink.org/doc/?doc=257828321/Piermont-Marsh-Fact-Finding-Meeting-3-Summary-010715     as dstudeba stated above?

Comment: The /..... is trimmed off by the call to LEFT inside the REPLACE which has a search for the first / after the number - the LOCATE does need to know where to start (char 28) - which would be a problem if the original URL was variable length - but will work if it is fixed as I commented

Comment: In the process of making test copy of mysql and ran into some errors. Will post when successful.

Comment: `UPDATE wp_whaz19_posts SET post_content=REPLACE(LEFT(post_content, LOCATE('/', post_content, 28)-1), 'https://www.scribd.com/doc/', 'https://www.hrnerr.org/doc/?doc=')`
may be a bit off, since it drastically truncates "post_content", e.g. `<p style="text-align: center;font-size: 20px"><em>What do we know about the water quality in the vicinity of Piermont Marsh?<`. And another: `'<h1>Where can I find more information about...<` Seems like the ending < is a clue?

Comment: Could the html tags be causing some confusion for the LOCATE?