# Using UPDATE and REPLACE With Wildcards

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, replace, sql-update

```
UPDATE database_posts 
SET post_content = REPLACE (post_content,'%submitted     by%%%%%', '');
```

Is it possible in SQL to perform an `UPDATE` and `REPLACE` using wildcards? I'm trying to remove the author from the post_content column, everything after/including `%submitted by%%%%%`.

The `submitted by` value is always different. I've tried using the query above with no luck.

Thanks!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL for replace with wildcard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001172/mysql-for-replace-with-wildcard)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would make your question much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep everything up to `submitted by` and nothing after, you can use `substring_index()`:

```
UPDATE database_posts 
    SET post_content = SUBSTRING_INDEX(post_content, 'submitted     by', 1)
    WHERE post_content LIKE '%submitted     by%';
```

I have no idea what all the spaces are between "submitted" and "by", but they are in your question.