# sql query remove hashtag

Tags: sql, replace, mysql-workbench

i've wanted to remove this hashtag entirely (including the words). I've used the update statement with replace the value but it didn't work.

[[image]]

```
update abc_db.test
    set caption_text = replace(caption_text, '#%', '')
```

Comment: Can you give some more data samples.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38225166/using-update-and-replace-with-wildcards

Answer (score -1):

`replace()` doesn't take wildcards.  Can you put in the characters?

```
update abc_db.test
    set caption_text = replace(caption_text, '#naeeanpoly', '');
```

Comment: yes i can but there are more than 1 hashtag, so i would like to have a universal method