# Query mysql Replace in Wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I need to run a query for all posts in a WordPress (+30.000)

To remove all content from *
only:

I'm reading about possibilites like:

```
UPDATE wp_posts
  SET post_content = 
  REPLACE( post_content, '</iframe>&', '</iframe>' );


SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('', '</iframe>', 1) as result;
```

But not working.

Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not seem to be a wildcard character for this, so I adapted the solution that is found here:
[MySQL for replace with wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21001172/mysql-for-replace-with-wildcard)

It only works if there is only 1  in the content of each post. Because it will take the content until and including that .

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = SUBSTR(post_content, 1, LOCATE('</iframe>', post_content)+8)
```

Notice that the +8 is the length of this string minus 1: `</iframe>`. You may want to test it on 1 row first.

I just realized this should only be applied to rows that DO have `</iframe>` in it, or else the rows without it will become empty.
So you need it like:

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = SUBSTR(post_content, 1, LOCATE('</iframe>', post_content)+8) WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM wp_posts WHERE post_content LIKE '%</iframe>%');
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I didn't express myself well (I'm also very new to mysql).

I have to remove all the content of all posts of a WP from the string </iframe>

What I wanted to put in my first message is to replace

</iframe>* (all that goes after </iframe>)

for only </iframe>

Comment: It worked perfectly.

UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = SUBSTR(post_content, 1, LOCATE('</iframe>', post_content)+8)

Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you double check that posts/pages without iframes in them did not become empty? If not, no problem!